# Ayuda con pase a producción con Django 1.9

Tags: python, django, apache, deployment

Necesito ayuda para desplegar un proyecto django en un servidor de producción, he realizado el siguiente proceso:

1. Tengo el servidor Ubuntu configurado
2. He creado el entorno virtual
3. He instalado django.
4. Ejecuto ./manage.py runserver dominio:puerto

Pero al acceder a localhost se muestra la pagina por defecto de apache, con el mensaje "It Works".

No se donde debo ubicar los archivos de mi aplicación y me gustaría saber si quizás estoy omitiendo algún paso importante o debo realizar alguna configuración adicional en Apache?

**Mi configuración es :**

- **Servidor Web:** Apache2
- **Hosting:** Strato
- **Python:** 3.5
- **Django:** 1.9

**EDITO:** Una duda que tengo siguiendo la documentación oficial, que me he leído ya un par de veces es donde tienen que apuntar las rutas del **WSGIScriptAlias** y el **WSGIPythonPath** dentro de la configuración de Apache2.

**WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py** (la primera barra es lo que me hace dudar, no se si tiene que apuntar a la raíz como aquí o el vhost donde quiero tener la web).

**WSGIPythonPath /path/to/mysite.com** (y en teoría este debe apuntar donde tengo el python instalado, correcto?).

**EDITO:**

(Al final he seguido en apache ya que no puedo migrar el servidor a nginx).

Después de haber configurado el VirtualHost en Apache2 siguiendo el ejemplo:

- **Ahora cuando accedo a midominio.com me sale un 403 Forbidden.** (eso a que podría ser debido? A que tengo que darle permisos a la carpeta del proyecto? O directamente hay algún directorio mal referenciado?)
- **Con el VirtualHost es suficiente o debo iniciar algún proceso para que me arranque el django?**
- **Hay que redireccionar el puerto 8000 al 80?**

**EDITO:** Aqui dejo mi VirtualHost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/dominio.com/chewbacca.dominio.com"

    Alias "/media" "/var/www/vhosts/dominio.com/chewbacca.dominio.com/django-project/chewbacca_project/media"
    Alias "/static" "/var/www/vhosts/dominio.com/chewbacca.dominio.com/django-project/chewbacca_project/static"

    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/dominio.com/chewbacca.dominio.com/django-project/chewbacca_project/static/>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/dominio.com/chewbacca.dominio.com/django-project/chewbacca_project/media/>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess chewie python-path=/var/www/vhosts/dominio.com/chewbacca.dominio.com/django-project/:/var/www/vhosts/dominio.com/chewbacca.dominio.com/django-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup chewie
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/dominio.com/chewbacca.dominio.com/django-project/chewbacca_project/chewbacca_project/wsgi.py
    WSGIPassAuthorization On

    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/dominio.com/chewbacca.dominio.com/django-project/chewbacca_project/chewbacca_project>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>
```

**EDITO:** Creo que uno de los problemas que tengo es que el servidor funciona con **PLESK**, pero bueno.

El log de Apache me da el siguiente error:

- **Fatal Python error: PyEval_AcquireThread: NULL new thread state**

**[ssl:warn] [pid 14845] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for chewbacca.midominio.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name**

**EDITO:** Al final he podido arreglar los problemas, uno de los problemas que tuve (y importante) es que no había creado el symbolic link de pip3 a pip (**ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip**) después de todo eso, ya me ha funcionado. AHORA SIIIII! ;) Lo del mod_python y mod_wsgi pude encontrarlo en google y lo hice.

Muchas gracias!

**EDITO:** Al final he conseguido poner el proyecto y todo perfecto, pero instalando las dependencias (**DjangoRestFramework, Pillow, Psycopg2**) acto seguido he hecho un **service apache2 restart** y puf... ha dejado de funcionar ha vuelto a dar error 500. **Recomiendo instalar todas las dependencias antes, asi el script de python no se corrompe**

**EDITO:** Después de 15 días de volverme loco cada día, he logrado que me funcione el WSGI, el problema viene ahora en que estoy haciendo cambios en el proyecto y no se reflejan en la parte en producción, ahora bien si hago un **runserver** y entro por el puerto 8000 si que me muestra el proyecto real (con los cambios que yo he hecho), alguien sería tan amable de decirme porque me pasa eso?, no basta con poner todo eso, me dejo algo más?

No me sale ningún error de imports, ni de nada, incluso he hecho un **./manage.py check --deploy** y me da 8 warnings (normales), que me falta? Estoy haciendo algo mal? Tambien he hecho un **./manage.py test proyecto** y me sale que no hay ningún fallo.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow! Pongo aquí un enlace de interés: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Comment: Hola @RuralGalaxy, Hay muchas posibles respuestas para tu planteamiento, por lo que te recomiendo que leas el tema [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) con el objeto que mejores la calidad de tu publicación.

Comment: Si eres nuevo en el tema, te recomiendo revisar a fondo este tutorial.
[Tutorial Django 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/intro/tutorial01/) Aqui te explica, atravez de diferentes temas, la configuracion de "Vistas, Urls, Modelos" que son las bases de Django

Comment: El comando `runserver` es solo para ambiente de testing, no deberías tener que ejecutar ese comando si estás en producción

Comment: Lo sé, pero lo digo para dejar claro de que de ese modo todo funciona correctamente, el problema es el deployment.

Comment: Te recomiendo que reformules tu pregunta. Divídela en varias preguntas separadas, una para cada duda que tengas. Las preguntas de mala calidad producen, como puedes ver, respuestas de mala calidad. Indica **qué documentación estás leyendo**, incluye enlaces y los archivos de configuración de Apache necesarios (elimina contraseñas y datos personales).

Comment: Puedes seguir también el checklist de deployment que esta en la documentación oficial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/checklist/

Comment: Muchísimas gracias @Avara la mejor respuesta hasta ahora, muy claro (al final he seguido en apache ya que no puedo migrar el servidor a nginx).

Después de haber configurado el VirtualHost en Apache2 siguiendo el ejemplo:

-  **Ahora cuando accedo a midominio.com me sale un 403 Forbidden.** (eso a que podría ser debido? A que tengo que darle permisos a la carpeta del proyecto? O directamente hay algún directorio mal referenciado?)

- **Con el VirtualHost es suficiente o debo iniciar algún proceso para que me arranque el django?**

- **Hay que redireccionar el puerto 8000 al 80?**

Comment: De nada! :) ¿Puedes editar la pregunta y poner tu fichero de apache para ver dónde puede estar el problema? Con el virtualhost debería ser suficiente. Con respecto al puerto, tu proyecto se está ejecutando con wsgi, no con el runserver por lo que ya se está ejecutando correctamente por el puerto 80 ;)

Comment: El último <directory> te sobra un "chewbacca_project", tendría que ser <Directory /var/www/vhosts/dominio.com/chewbacca.dominio.com/django-project/chewbacca_project>

Comment: ponia dos chewbacca porque el fichero .wsgi esta dentro del segundo chewbacca_project, ahora pruebo.

Comment: @RuralGalaxy, el fallo que comentas (PyEval_AcquireThread: NULL new thread state) puede aparecer si tienes  mod_wsgi y mod_python activados a la vez, te dejo el link a un blog que comenta de forma más detallada este problema que en un comentario no entra bien :) https://enlook.wordpress.com/2015/01/29/error-fatal-python-error-pyeval_acquirethread-null-new-thread-state/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Con respecto a tus dudas:

**WSGIScriptAlias:** tiene que apuntar a la ruta absoluta con respecto a tu virtualhost, es decir, `/`. Si pusieses `/miruta`, tu url quedaría, por ejemplo, `midominio.com/miruta/`

**WSGIPythonPath**: tiene que apuntar donde tienes python instalado, seguramente, **a tu entorno virtual**, por ejemplo: `/var/www/[PATH_AL_PROYECTO]/venv/local/bin/python2.7`

Una configuración posible para tu apache podría ser algo parecido a esta:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>    
    DocumentRoot /var/www/[RAIZ_DEL_APACHE/HOSTING]

    Alias /media /var/www/[PATH_A_CARPETA_MEDIA]
    Alias /static /var/www/[PATH_A_CARPETA_STATICS]

    <Directory /var/www/[PATH_A_CARPETA_STATICS]>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/[PATH_A_CARPETA_MEDIA]>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess [NOMBRE_QUE_QUIERAS] python-path=/var/www/[PATH_AL_PROYECTO]:/var/www/[PATH_AL_PROYECTO]/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup [NOMBRE_QUE_QUIERAS]
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/[PATH_AL_PROYECTO]/[PATH_DEL_WSGI]/wsgi.py
    WSGIPassAuthorization On

    <Directory /var/www/[PATH_AL_PROYECTO]>
    <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
    </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Para entender mejor lo que tienes que sustituir, supongamos lo siguiente:

Tu proyecto tiene estas rutas:

```
/var/www/htm/
|--miproyecto/
   |--venv/ --> carpeta donde has creado tu entorno virtual, supongamo con virtualenv
   |--statics/  --> carpeta donde se almacenan los ficheros estáticos cuando haces python manage.py collectstatic
   |--media/ --> carpeta de los ficheros multimedia
   |--miapp/
   |  |--wsgi.py
   |--manage.py
```

Con esto, el ejemplo de apache anterior quedaría como:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>    
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    Alias /media /var/www/html/miproyecto/media/
    Alias /static /var/www/html/miproyecto/statics/

    <Directory /var/www/html/miproyecto/statics/>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/html/miproyecto/media/>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess miproyectoweb python-path=/var/www/html/miproyecto/:/var/www/html/miproyecto/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup miproyectoweb
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/miproyecto/miapp/wsgi.py
    WSGIPassAuthorization On

    <Directory /var/www/html/miproyecto>
    <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
    </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

De todas formas, si hablamos de despliegues a producción en general con Django, el despliegue preferido por la mayoría es con [Django + Gunicorn + Supervisor + Nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-14-04).

También recomiendo, si se quiere realizar un proyecto de despliegue continuo, echar un vistazo a librerías como [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/)

Comment: Si @RuralGalaxy la marca como buena le doy la recompensa :)